# Django user signup by Ajax request

Tags: javascript, django

I am new to web development and I m trying to signup a user by using ajax call.
    I m looking for "status" : "OK" in the response for removing overlay and changing the login option with the user profile option. But i m getting this response from django back end which is -:

```
html: "{"status": "ok", "html": "\n     <div class=\"notification\">\n <span><a>Notifications</a></span>\n            <div class=\"count_pop\"></div>\n            <div class=\"not_pop not\">\n\n\n                 <div>\n\n                     <a href=\"/see_all/\"target=\"_blank\">See all notifications</a>\n        </div>\n        <ul>\n\n        </ul>\n            </div>\n\n          </div>\n\n\n        <div class=\"user_profile\">\n            <picture> \n                    <img src=\"/media/2017/03/default_profile_pic.png\"/>\n                </picture>\n            <a>ab cd</a>\n        <div class=\"user_pop\">\n        <ul>\n           <li><a href=\"/user/abcd\">Profile</a></li>\n            <li><a href=\"/accounts/password/change/\">Change Password</a></li>\n         <li><a href=\"/user/settings/\">Settings</a></li>\n            <li><a href=\"/logout/\">Logout</a></li>\n        </ul>\n            </div>\n </div>\n\n    </div>", "user": {"id": 105, "name": "ab cd"}, "next": "/"}"
```

how can I get "status": "ok" ?

**EDIT** Ajax request-

```
$(document).on('click', '.signup form button', function () {
    $('.signup form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            })
var name = $('#id_full_name').val();
                var username = $('#id_username_s').val();
                var email = $('#id_email').val();
                var password1 = $('#id_password1').val();
                var password2 = $('#id_password2').val();




  if (name && username && email && password1 && password2 != '') {
                $.Ajax().post('/signup/', {full_name: name, username: username, email: email, password1: password1, password2: password2,},
                    function (d) {

                    if (d.status == "OK") {
                        $('.overlay').remove();
                        $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
                        $('.user_div').html(d.html);
                        }});}
    });


**Django View** 

    def logged_in_response(user, next_to='/', _json=False, is_signup=None):
        """
        returns a JsonResponse/json
        Data for the logged in user to set states in front end
        """
        data = {'status': 'ok',
                'next': next_to,
                'user': {'id': user.id,
                         'name': user.full_name
                         },
                'html': render_to_string('account/user_header.html', {'user': user})
                }

        return json.dumps(data) if _json else JsonResponse(data)
```

this is a copy pasted code. its works fine when signing in . It sends all the data but while signing up, it sends response in html key.

Comment: Post your view and ajax request

Comment: struggling with formatting error...

Comment: try `d.html.status` instead of `d.status`

Comment: nothing happens with d.html.status.. and when i try to alert d.html.status... it shows undefined..

Comment: make a call back function for the error handling and try to alert that. I think your response from the server is not 200 so it is handled as an error.

Comment: status is 200..   Request URL:http://localhost:8000/signup/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000